# Rails - what is the most efficient way to build query for multiple tags

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this situation:

Two models:
 - Meal 
 - Tag

With a `many-to-many` relationship, So product can have assigned many tags.

There is additional table for association (`meal_id`, `tag_id`)
Then user choose some tags (for example 8).

I must write query in Rails (but can be only sql idea), which return:

1. meals which has assigned at least one tag from chosen by user.
2. meals which has assigned all chosen tags.

I don't know how to do it in most efficient way. Could you help me a little?

Meal.rb

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

Tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
end
```

Comment: The additional table you say (meal_id, tag_id) is another model (I think), what is its name? By the way, why do you need another table for association if you can add a column `tag_id` into you Product table, and `meal_id` to your Tag table in order to comply the relationships

Comment: No it isn't another table. It is just association. I cannot add tag_id to meal table and meal_id to tag table, because meal can have assigned more than one tag.

Comment: @user2948135 You should show the code that is in your models `Product` and `Tag` so we can see how your Associations are setup. But your comment above is wrong, in fact you CAN do what you said you can't, it is called a has_many Association. See docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: But when you have has_many association in both directions, then you have additional (associated) table, yes? that is my case. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to get `Meal` with dynamic `tag_ids`. You have to collect `tag_ids` then you join `Meal` by `tag_ids`

```
tag_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Meal.joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?)', tags_ids).group("meals.id")
                    .having("COUNT(meals.id) >= ?", tag_ids.length)
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

To return the queries you want try the following:

1. *"Meals which has assigned at least one tag"*:

```rb
    # we will store meal objects in this array
    #the ones that has at least one tag
    meals = []

    # go over all meals
    Meal.all.each do |meal|

      # if meal has tags store it
      if !meal.tags.blank?
        meals << meal
      end

    end

    # then I have all meals with at least one tag in my array called meals
    # and I can do whatever I want with it
    meals.each do |m|
      #do something with each meal
    end

    how_many_meals_with_one_tag_at_least = meals.count
```

2. *"Meals which has assigned all chosen tags"*. I think you mean: "Meals which has assigned all existent tags".

```rb
    # again our array to store meals
    meals = []

    maximumTags = Tag.all.count   

    Meal.all.each do |meal|

      if meal.tags.count == maximumTags
        meals << meal
      end

    end

    meals.each do |m|
      #do something with your meal with all tags assigned
    end
```

I know this is approach is more ruby than sql, but it's easy to implement and gets you there.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I mean what I wrote. In first case should be "at least one tag from chosen". So it is relate with quiet hard sql query I think.